# nothing shown in java applet html file chooser

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, filechooser

When I use java applet to create a open file button, it can show a file chooser for me to choose the file, but when i access to the applet html page generated by netbean, a file chooser is shown after I clicked the open file button, but no directory is shown and I cannot select the file. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: fix the code, maybe?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example). 2) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 3) Is this AWT or Swing?  4) Do you realize that an applet needs to be digitally signed and trusted by the end user before it can use a file chooser? ..

Comment: .. 5) Be sure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show.  If there is no output at the default level, raise the level and try it again.